# use Tortoise git does not appear to be a git repository

Tags: git

I use `tortoise git` when I click git clone
set URL  `ssh://git@192.168.3.98/var/www/git.repos/myproject.git`

and click ok button  ,showing error message

```
fatal: 'var/www/git.repos/myproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists

git did not exit cleanly
```

this message. 
`192.168.3.98/var/www/git.repos/mypoject.git` this here.
space directory.

how this error message solve?

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
ssh://git@192.168.3.98:/var/www/git.repos/myproject.git
```

Notice the ':' before the path.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SSH client exe to OpenSSH ssh.exe for Windows 10 machine.

Settings > Network > SSH Client

`C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`

Previous Value was `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\sh.exe`

Notes:

- I did not add `:` to url.
- OpenSSH was already installed.